# Granularity of Interface

Tags: design-patterns, interface, architecture

on my work today i came to struggle with the slice of my Interfaces.

To maintain some masterdata in my application, i build an context. This context takes an dataprovider to take the Information it needs and bring it to an strategy to persist.

In first try i build an Method in my context for setting the Dataprovider. E. G. one file based and one from database.

```
Context->setData(MyProvider->getData() ) ;
```

The dataprovider needs some different settings to Do the work. The Filebased need the Filepath and the databaseprovider an Modelobject.

Now im Not sure, what's the best way of defining the interface.
Make an general Interface "Provider" and care about the return type of the getData Method. Or go with inheritance an build a special interface for Fileprovider and on for the Database.

```
Interface Fileprovider extends IProvider { void setPath(String Path) ;}
```

Or third possibility just do a standalone interface for every Provider.

Thanks for you toughts

Comment: Just my 2 cents, but I think you should use a single Interface which declares the methods which will be implemented by concrete classes, then in your classes you can setup the settings via the constructor. So you would have classes `DatabaseProvider(Model Object)` constructor, and `FileProvider(string filepath)` constructor and both implement IProvider which declares a method `getData()`

Comment: You could then have an object of IProvider inside your Context, and you can switch in and out any class object which Implements IProvider.

Comment: Thanks Ryan! Your view about it was interesting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest composition and a base `IProvider` interface (your second approach). Each provider will likely have some special features that are individual and therefore should be encapsulated (Interface Segregation Principle):

```
Main()
{
  Context context = new Context();

  IFileDataProvider fileDataProvider = new FileDataProvider();

  // Configure the provider
  fileDataProvider->setPath("c:\data");

  context->setProvider(fileDataProvider);

  // Get data. Internally this data is read from the local filesystem
  DataResultObject data = context->getData();

  IDatabaseProvider databaseProvider = new DatabaseProvider();

  // Configure the provider
  databaseProvider->login();

  context->setProvider(databaseProvider);

  // Get data. Internally this data is now read from the database
  DataResultObject data = context->getData();

  // A test case would fake the data provider to reduce complexity and improve performance. 
  // To achieve this a third implementation (a dummy) would be required.
  IProvider fakeDataProvider = new MockDataProvider();
  context->setProvider(fakeDataProvider);

  // Get test data. Internally this data is created by the fake data provider
  DataResultObject data = context->getData();
}

interface IProvider 
{
  DataResultObject getData();
}

interface IFileDataProvider extends IProvider
{
  void setPath(String path);
}

class FileDataProvider implements IFileDataProvider 
{
  void setPath(String path)
  {
    this->path = path;
  }

  DataResultObject getData()
  {
    return readFromFilesystem();
  }
}

interface IDatabaseProvider extends IProvider
{
  void login();
}

class DatabaseProvider implements IDatabaseProvider 
{
  private String credentials = "login credentials";

  void login()
  {
    login(this->credentials);
  }

  DataResultObject getData()
  {
    return readFromDatabase();
  }
}

class MockDataProvider implements IProvider
{
  DataResultObject getData()
  {
    // return empty or dummy data
    return new DataResultObject();
  }
}

class Context
{
  IProvider provider;

  public Context(IProvider provider)
  {
    this.provider = provider;
  }

  public DataResultObject getData()
  {
    return this.provider->getData();
  }

  public void setContext(IProvider provider) 
  {
    this.provider = provider;
  }
}
```

If the `IProvider` instance will change on the same `Context`object, then I would add a setter to switch instances. Otherwise the constructor is the better choice.

Using a dedicated interface for each provider type would eliminate the option to switch between providers since it would eliminate polymorphism. The switching could be useful when you write unit tests. You can then easily mock the database or filesystem.

And using a single shared interface would force the e.g. `DatabaseProvider` to implement redundant `FileDataProvider` specific methods. This can be very annoying and confusing when classes are containing dummy implementations. The Interface Segregation Principle ( the 'i' in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID)) recommends for some good reasons to avoid this kind of design.

Comment: Thanks for you explanation!

Comment: @Felix What was the question ?

Comment: I just wanted to go more detail, but i read your answer again. It was about the definiton for the argument in the constructor. I was a little confused, because this scenario leads to more interfaces than classes. But in the end, you can change the object for the store, without touching more than one class!

Comment: @Felix Yes, more interfaces because of the Interface Segregation. You can configure e.g. the specific `FileDataProvider` implementation through the more specialized `IFileDataProvider` interface. Because later you are only interested in the data, to access the `FileDataProvider` via the `IProvider` interface is sufficient. I will update the usage example (the main method) and add a DatabasProvider to show what I mean. please wait

Comment: @Felix I updated the example. Now you can see how `Context` can use all different ÌProvider` implementations. Also you can see that because of the Interface Segregation each specialization only needs to implement its specific members, but all have the same `getData()` method. When we would have used one big shared interface for all, then e.g. the `MockDataProvider` would be forced to implement the useless `login()` and `setPath(string)` members.

Comment: @Felix Sorry. To be conform with your example I should have use `setModel(ModelObject)` instead of `login()` as the specialization method of `IDatabaseProvider`

Comment: Thanks, That is a great example. I think i improved my way of coding!